# O que é o banner do lado direito do site?

Tags: debate

O que é o banner do lado direito do site? Publicidade? Brincadeira de 1 de Abril?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É publicidade. A Stack Exchange está lançando um novo relógio de bolso, concorrente do Apple Watch. A personagem que aparece na tela é o *Stacky*, um assistente pessoal ativado por comandos de voz, como a Siri. O aparelho se comunica por Wi-Fi com o seu computador, e os 3 botões facilitam a vida dos usuários viciados no Stack Overflow: o primeiro dá um upvote na pergunta que estiver aberta no browser, o segundo dá downvote, e o terceiro vota para fechar.

Comment: É uma seca o _Stacky_ se não tiver um site da SE aberto tá sempre a dizer "Tenho fome"! Parece um Tamagotchi!

Comment: Ouvi dizer que o *Stacky* vem com uma implementação de redes neurais que identifica automaticamente os padrões de uso do site e, após algum treino, consegue realizar os votos pelo usuário automaticamente.

Answer (score 10):

*O Tamagochi em questão é o produto da SE para concorrer com PacMan do google.*

Nele, é possível competir com os demais sites da rede SE e ver quem *zera a internet primeiro*. (Nós não seremos primeiros a não ser que o @bfavaretto e/ou @utluiz liberem o espírito HueHueBr e coloquem o ClickHack para ficar clicando automático no lugar certo)

---

O objetivo da brincadeira é zerar a internet, ou seja, fazer com o site esteja sempre saudável. Para isso, é necessário que algumas pessoas estejam lá clicando e fazendo com que os ♥♥♥♥ estejam sempre cheios.

**ASK** - Aumenta o ♥ em perguntas. Mas afeta negativamente o ♥ das respostas.

**ANSWER** - Aumenta o ♥ em respostas. É o que mantem o site. Muitas respostas com boa qualidade gera tráfego.

**UPVOTE** -  Aumenta o ♥ em usuários. Usuários felizes faz bem. :D :D

**DOWNVOTE** - É necessário para aumentar o ♥ em qualidade do site em geral. Em contra-partida, afeta negativamente a felicidade dos usuários. :(

**CLOSE** - Aumenta ♥ em qualidade. Em contra-partida, afeta negativamente as perguntas.

**FLAG** -  É um recurso que preenche todos os quesitos do site com, pelo menos, um ♥. Existe um número máximo de FLAGS que podem ser usadas. (Não sei quanto).

**NOTHING** - Se o site estiver bem, e não for necessário fazer nada, use-se disso. Não faça isso sempre. Todo o site precisa de atenção e nosso *game/site* também.

**RESTART** - Faz com o que o jogo volte para o início. Ou seja, volte à area51, depois estágio de beta privado e tenha que evoluir para beta público e posteriormente, se graduar. 
**Faça isso nos sites dos nossos concorrentes. É muito recomendado.**

*Se ninguém votar durante algumas rodadas, ele volta para a area51.

Tem um ranking aqui: [Ranking](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/stackegg/leaderboard)

---

[image: Conseguimos fazer isso aí na hora do almoço ontem.]
Apenas para incentivar os users (ou seriam players?), conseguimos isso na hora do almoço (BR) ontem.

Comment: Quem são os nossos concorrentes?

Comment: Todos que estão na nossa frente no ranking. xD http://pt.stackoverflow.com/stackegg/leaderboard